# 'Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive' error when specifying any domain

Tags: content-security-policy

I've read the [Content Security Policy docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives) and have entries for my image sources. My values match the examples in the docs, but Chrome complains the valus aren't valid:

```
Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'pbs.twimg.com'.
Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'https://pbs.twimg.com'.
```

The header is:

```
Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only:default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' mycompany.com *.typekit.net *.stripe.com *.mxpnl.com *.twitter.com;img-src 'self' data:; pbs.twimg.com;font-src fonts.googleapis.com fonts.gstatic.com *.typekit.net;report-uri /csp-violation
```

Comment: What, exactly, do your values look like? Use the Net tab of the Chrome developer tools to see what the browser is receiving. Don't just show us the error message and expect us to reverse engineer what you typed from it.

Comment: @Quentin added. I don't think much reverse engineering should be required: Chrome is reporting on the values as given to Chrome.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have a semi-colon after `data:` and before `pbs.twimg.com` so `pbs.twimg.com` is being treated as a *directive-name* instead of as part of a *directive-value*.